# ng-options is not returning value scheme as scheme.name for scheme in schemeList track by scheme.name

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Schemes drop down: if write like below

`<select name="scheme" ng-model="scheme" ng-options="scheme as scheme.name for scheme in schemeList track by scheme.name"></select>`

My ng-reapeat filter is not working:

`<tr ng-repeat="request in requestLists | filter:requestStatus:schemeName:scheme}">`

if I use drop down below it's working:

`<select name="scheme" ng-model="scheme">`
`<option value="">`All`</option>`
`<option value="sbm">`sbm`</option>`
`<option value="nulm">`nulm`</option>`
`</select>`

may i know what wrong i have written in ng-options in the above select

Comment: Understood the problem. I have to add "scheme.name" in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Understood the problem. I have to add "scheme.name" in ng-repeat.
`<tr ng-repeat="request in requestLists | filter:requestStatus:schemeName:scheme.name}">`

Answer (score 0):

best way to do is the following::
            `<select name="scheme" ng-model="scheme.name" >
                <option value="" disabled>Select Scheme</option>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option ng-repeat="scheme in schemeList">{{scheme.name}}</option>
            </select>`